# python shifting row back by one

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below data which I got through `pandas.read_html`

```
      Column1      Column2     Column3      Column4      Column5
0     Entry_1      Value_1     Record_1     test_1       NaN
1     Entry_2      Value_2     Record_2     test_2       NaN
2     Entry_3      Value_3     Record_3     test_3       NaN
3     Entry_4      Value_4     Record_4     test_4       NaN
4     Entry_5      Value_5     Record_5     test_5       NaN
5     Entry_6      Value_6     Record_6     test_6       NaN
6     Entry_7      Value_7     -            Record_7     test_7
```

How do I use `pandas` to shift `Column4` and `Column5` back by 1 space so that it will align itself?

Comment: how do you *detect* that there is a problem? you can use the same algorithm to fix the original data before loading to pandas...

Comment: This was the data that I got from the table I pulled through the use of `pandas.read_html`. So this is what I got when I `print df`

Comment: Any thoughts as to how I can solve this?

Comment: load the html as string, regex-replace the invalid pieces to get valid structure as needed for loading to pandas... without the original html example for lines 5 and 6, I am not able to say anything more concrete. and looks like other people don't know how to fix after it gets to pandas either (it is possible in principle though, if you cannot share the html and no one replies by next few weeks, I can have a look when I will have more time)